# Is it safe to arrive at Amboseli National Park (Kenya) at night?

Tags: safety, kenya, safari

I'm wondering if it's safe to drive to Amboseli at night. We are planning to leave Nairobi at around 3pm Saturday to our lodge, which is located near the Amboseli National Park (not within the park borders).

I'm asking for general safety from animals, humans (robbers?) and also traffic (if there are lots of trucks speeding, etc).

Comment: To confirm, is the lodge within the park borders?

Comment: What kind of dangers you are asking about?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answers. The lodge is NOT within the park borders. I'm asking for general safety from animals, humans (robbers?) and also traffic (if there are lots of trucks speeding, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Most park entrances are only open during daylight hours (6am to 6pm), so entering after hours might be considered a violation of park rules.

I didn't pay attention to signs along the roads when last there (too busy looking for wildlife while my driver did the navigation), so can't say how well signposted the routes are within the park.  But that could be a huge factor when driving in the dark.

Best bet is to call or email the lodge office and ask them.  They would know the park restrictions on nighttime driving or entry.

In terms of safety from animals or poachers... I would think that poachers would not use the main park roads to avoid running into park officials, so you wouldn't likely encounter any night time hunts (but you might need to explain why you are out there if you encounter a ranger patrol).

But there could be more wildlife on or near the road as they would be used to no traffic at night, so you would need to keep the eyes open.

Comment: Hmm, while probably a valid answer for in-park-night-driving, she does say the lodge is 'near the park', so hopefully that means outside, and won't be violating the rules. Which probably means they're wondering about roads near the park...

Comment: If she is only going somewhere near Amboseli, then most of her drive will be in daylight hours on paved highways, likely arriving at her hotel at dusk (depending on where it actually is).

Comment: I've asked as a comment on her question to clarify, if she's just asking about the road then answer may need updating. Otherwise yours is fine, matches my experience of game parks in South Africa.

Comment: Question has been updated in the comments, answer may need to change now :/